# Ajax Request Error on Cordova Android App on first execution

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, phonegap

since a few days, the Ajax Request will throw an error when the Android app is new installed and open for the first time. I have to close and reopen the app then everything works as it should. Running the App in the Phonegap emulator or build for iphone, everything works fine. But Build für Android brings the Error. Here is my js code:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://www.meinonlinewunschzettel.de",  
    data: dataString,
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function(){ }, 
    success: function(data){
        //Some Code
        }         

    },
    complete: function(){

        },
    error: function(xhr, status, error){
        alert(xhr.status+status+error); //Resault: '0error'
    }            
    });
```

does anyone have any idea what the problem is?

Comment: I have been having the exact same issue.

There have been a few reports of the identical issue on iOS a year or two ago:



https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/issues/22


https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=793648

Which was to do with the underlying WKWebView not correctly syncing cookies.


Not sure if a future update has added this 'feature' to Android. Does your authentication mechanism rely on session cookies being stored?

Comment: no, I do not use cookies with the ajax request. The Request goes to a php File which supplies data from my mysql database.

Comment: This error occurred with me for the first time on 03.08.2019. That was before I upgraded from cli-8.1.1 to cli-9.0.0. If I have older apk builds from March or April installed and have the same problem. After closing and reopening everything goes. That's crazy

Comment: Complementary: $.ajax call goes to the error, but the php on serverside is working. In my example, the registered user is created in the Mysql database

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=991107

It is an underlying issue with WebView 76, the Chrome team have fixed and rolled out a new version of 76 on 9th August